# ASP.net C# dropdownlist does not work for chrome and result always return default option

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspx-user-control

Hi I have few dropdownlist but one of it doest not work properly, when I choose from the list and after submit, it will keeping get the default item value and not record the one I choose from list if I browse from Googlo Chrome. I try to clear cache and so on but it does not work. This happen for one of the dropdownlist only, the other work well.

Below is my code:

```
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>Type:</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="WOType" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="WO_Type" DataValueField="WO_Type" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value="" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage=" Type is required." ControlToValidate="WOType"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:String %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [WO_Type] FROM [WOTYPE]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>Product:</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="Product_id" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Product_Product" DataValueField="Product_Product" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value="" Selected="False" ></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage=" Product is required." ControlToValidate="Product_id"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:String %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Product_Product] FROM [PRODUCT] ORDER BY [Product_Product]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
```

Below is Code behind code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }

    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            con.Open();
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);
            string contentType = FileAttachment.PostedFile.ContentType;
            using (Stream fs = FileAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream)
            {

                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["String"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
                    {

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into WORKORDER(WOType,Product) values (@WOType,@Product)", conn);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"WOType", WOType.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Product", Product_id.Text);
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        conn.Close();
                     }   
                  }
           }
   }
```

The Type dropdownlist can return the list I choose, but the Product dropdownlist is force to return the default item . Please help

Comment: Post your `Page_Load` codebehind.

Comment: @JamshaidKamran I already upload the code behind code

Comment: WOType.Text return the list I choose , but  Product_id.Text keep return the value I did not choose

Comment: From where this Product_id is coming? Let us know how the value is getting bound to it?

Comment: DropDownList ID="Product_id" . The list is taken from database as the code above datasource from sql server, and I can see the list from UI, but when select the list, after submit it will capture the default value.

Comment: Can you verify if the dropdown is not being cleared before the data is posted?